# Receive acknowledgement of Youtube video access from your page

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

Is there a way to do this from Youtube, not from an embedded video?

Answer (score 0):

Not reliably.

The only way you can tell where a user is coming from is using the `HTTP_REFERER` header which is sent by the browser, and which you can access in PHP using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.

However, whether this header is sent or not is entirely up to the client. A user can decide to block the header. Firewalls sometimes tend to block it as well.

If, however, you are the author of that Youtube video, you could change the annotation and add a parameter to the query string (such as `http://your.site/?from=youtube`) and then retrieve that on the script end from `$_GET['FROM']`.